# SearchView like in Google Maps Application

Tags: android, searchview

I'm going to tell how to is mysearch view.When Application starts keyboard must not show up, and search view is always expanded mode.

i am using this layout for search view btw it isn't menu item

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchview"
        android:background="@color/Transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>


Arama = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchview);
    Arama.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus) {
                Arama.onActionViewCollapsed();
                Arama.setQuery("", false);
            }
        }
    });
    Arama.onActionViewExpanded();
    Arama.setQueryHint("Article");

<activity
        ....
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="...." />
    </activity>
```

when i do this,when application starts, my keyboard automatically shows up but i don't want it.When click, it will show up

How can i do that? Thanks for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this tag in your activity's manifest declaration if you wish not to show your keyboard when activity starts, but want to show when user clicks inside any `EditText`-

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" ... >
    ...
</activity>
```

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` to never show your keyboard.

Not in application tag, in Activity tag.

Check other softInputMode tags [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: And let me be sure, You don't want your keyboard to pop up when activity starts, but you want to show it when you click in your search box, right? and check my edited answer.

Comment: it still pop up maybe we have to disable automatically focus on search view

Comment: I am really sorry for being sloppy, actually you were supposed to use tag 'stateHidden'; not 'stateVisible' :( My bad. Please try and let me know if worked.

Comment: now works but sorry i can't vote to you requires 15 ,thank you for helping me :)

Comment: No issue, Happy to help out. Welcome.